Copy attribute menu doesn't work on Blender 4.1.1
anyone experiences the copy attribute menu doesn't pop up at all even activating the addon? I've tried to disable other addons to see if something conflicted, no luck. It drives me crazy cause I use the menu very often. I'm using Blender 4.1.1 on Windows 11

Works fine here with Ctrl-C even popping up if you just have one object in the scene.

Can confirm, I took the init.py file from the addon and run it in the script editor a couple of times and it started working globally even after restarting blender
